# Can't deploy Tableau Dashboards using ANT - No Version Mismatch

Tags: deployment, ant, einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, tableau-crm

**To start with, I'd like to say that I have the same SF version between the source and the target orgs (Spring 22).**

I'm trying to deploy a group of Einstein dashboards, and also dataflows, datasets and apps. Everytime I try to deploy them I get the following error:

Not available for deploy for this organization

[image]

I could successfully deploy them a couple of days before but now I can't. I deployed first the dataflows, run them, and then the dashboards. I'm getting this error now.

For the deployment, my user has the 'Tableau CRM Plus Admin' permission set assigned.

Thank you so much for the help on this!

Comment: I have no experience with Einstein migration... But have you tried to [retrieve metadata with a lower apiVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_build.htm) and deploy this? (I understand that the versions of your source and target org are in sync, but I'd be interested, if this makes the error go away.) Have you the ability to attempt to deploy temporarily with an Admin user ("API Enabled", "Modify All Data") and see if this would work?

Comment: This might be stupid but is TCRM enabled in the target org? Can you post a screenshot of this screen (**SETUP > FEATURE SETTINGS> ANALYTICS > GET STARTED**? URL
_https://<<YOUR ORG INSTANCE>>.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/InsightsSetupGettingStarted/home_ and also check the licence/SKU expiry from checkout.

Comment: The feature of Analytics is enabled in eht sandbox,a dn I also tried retrieveing the metadata with a lower API version (I used the 50 and 49) but it didn't work either. Nevertheless thank you very much for the help Felix and manjit. 

At the end I could deploy all the Einstein metadata by using changesets. That solved the situation for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this could help anyone:

At the end I couldn't figure out how to migrate the Einstein/Tableu metadata using ANT, so Instead I simply migrated it by using normal changests between my Sandbox and the Production org. That worked very well.

First I deployed the Dataflows. Before running them I granted read and edit access to the Analytics Cloud Integration User profile, over all of the objects involved in the Datasets/Dashboards, and made a full sync (from App Launcher > Analytics Studio > Data Manager > Connect) over all these objects as well. This is important before running the dataflows because otherwise they're very likely to fail due to lack of permissions to access a certain field or having outdated data.

After doing that and running the Dataflows, I deployed the dashboards also using changesets, and that was it.

If anyone knows how to solve the issue to be able to deploy the metadata using ANT it would be a great contribution to the question. Thank you all!